# Eclipse error when Adding Tomcat as server runtime environment

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, development-environment

When I try to add Tomcat as a server runtime environment in eclipse, I get the following error "No new server runtime environments were found"
The way I am trying to add Tomcat is as follows:
Click "Window"-> "preferences"
Expand "Server->Runtime Environments"
Click Search
In the directroy browser dialog, navigate to and select my Tomcat dir
"C:\program files\apache-tomcat-6.0.26"
Click "ok"
Does anyone know what eclipse is actually looking for when you tell it what folder to search in? If I knew this, I could troubleshoot myself a bit more.
I have tried re-installing tomcat, also installed the next version up (6.0.26)
but still eclipse cannot find it. The version of eclipse I am running is - 
"Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" Build id: 20090920-1017

Comment: What are you choosing for the JRE drop dwon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me but i'm using Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.